# Random document from a specific field query

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a document structure as this:

```
{_id:"XXXXXXXXX", contents:{...}, color:"red"}
```

I would like to get a **random document with a specific color**. For instance, a random document that's also "red".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://bdadam.com/blog/finding-a-random-document-in-mongodb.html

Comment: Think how randomnes works. If I open a cupboard with 10 items in it then I can pick a random item from one of the ten. If I want to pick a random "red" item, then I need to identify all things that are "red" and then pick something at random from that. So in short, you need to know the "list" of all "red" things before you can pick something random out of it. Depends on what sort of numbers you are talking about to make this feasible

Comment: .find({color:"red"})  returns all red things - I was thinking to have a query that would use that.

Comment: @Mia: so, at the very least, you can first get ids of all red things. Pick one id at random (in the app) and then go fetch that document directly.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev with over a million documents that's overkill

Comment: @Mia: well, getting random records from database is an old and difficult problem :)